# PDF Viewer iPad App

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, pdf

I'm looking to develop a *custom* PDF viewer for an iPad, which has features like:

- bookmarks
- search
- deep linking
- zoom
- jump to specific page

Does anyone know a code solution similar to this? I'm currently looking at [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) but am having a problem finding other options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've developed a custom reader like this which I've used for a handful of projects for clients.  Search & Highlight was by far the most difficult, followed by text selection.  Keeping memory usage low for large PDF's is tricky too.

I cant share my source.  But here's someone who has a free library that looks promising:

http://mobfarm.eu/fastpdfkit

https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit

(it doesn't look as if the source code is available?)

Comment: that looks exactly like what we're looking for.  Thanks for the tips/suggestion!

Comment: I have to check it out first.  Don't be greedy! :)

Comment: @Tom swift,one thing  i want to ask that can i use mobfarm pdf kit in my app.I mean that whether the app store accept it or not.Please let me know.

Comment: @Sabby - no idea.  I haven't used it myself.  I'm sure you could ask the developer.

Comment: @Tom i will look forward for that and thanks for your reply dear

Answer (score 14):

For a simple and effective PDF viewer, you can now (iOS 4.0+) use the QuickLook framework:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.dataSource = self;
previewController.delegate = self;
previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = indexPath.row;
[self presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
[previewController release];
```

You need to link against `QuickLook.framework` and `#include <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>`

For anything more complex, just grab the excellent [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com).

Comment: thanks!  
is there a way to use QuickLook.framework for displaying HTML? or is there something very similar I could replace it with for this purpose?

Comment: Very nice.. I had no idea this existed! Saved me a bunch of time and works great for quickly viewing PDFs!! I found this tutorial to show how to fully implement the delegate & datasource methods: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice example of a [pdf reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) on github. It does not do the advanced things (like text search), but it might be good as a starting place. Seems to do OK with large pdfs, so *maybe* the performance is not too bad.

Answer (score 2):

You could port Xpdf or the forked Poppler to iOS and use their rendering capabilities as well as retrieving information such as bookmarks and URI links from the PDF for use in your application.

Answer (score 2):

There is a payed option named http://pspdfkit.com/

I have been looking at the example and it seams to work the way I was hoping to find some code example

Comment: +1 this indeed is the only proper implementation that I found while researching the subject. Also note that the author is a really good and thorough developer -  that guy also backported UICollectionView to iOS5.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.labnol.org/software/ipad-pdf-reader-apps/13807/

**Update:**  I can't find any PDF component/library for iOS, which doesn't surprise me.  So here's a crazy alternative (so crazy it just might work):  Write your app in C#/.Net using [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/), and incorporate the free .Net library [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).  I have no idea if this would work or not.

Another idea might be to incorporate a web service (running on a server somewhere) that will convert your PDF into HTML for you.  Your server component can be written in any language, which expands your PDF-component options considerably.  And the things you want to do in your bullet points would be a lot easier to implement yourself with HTML.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to develop my own :-)

Comment: Well, your question was literally "Has anyone seen anything like this?" The answer is "yes". :)

Comment: @MusicGenesis question updated

Comment: Also, I apologize for my earlier snark. I clicked on the Ghostscript link, but somehow I perceived that as a PDF-viewing application instead of a code library.

Comment: If you can build the Ghostscript source as a framework for iOS, that looks like all you need right there.