# Download and View PDFs in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

I'm planning to develop an iPhone app in which will do the following:

1. download PDF file from my
   website.
2. open PDF file which is password
   protected
3. access this PDF file offline from
   the iPhone

I really want to know how to achieve the above, what classes to use and what tips should I consider?

Thanks

Comment: you may want to look at this similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949809/pdf-viewer-ipad-app

Comment: As yms.cu suggested above, a password protected PDF will need to be opened by a custom PDF viewer, which the above link has some decent info on.

Answer (score 2):

1. When downloading large files on mobile devices it's a good idea to save the data as it comes in. I suggest you use a good network library that performs all this work for you: [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) and [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) are both very good and actively maintained.
2. Since your pdf files are password protected you'll need to write a custom pdf viewer. For non-password protected pdf files you could have used the QuickLook framework to display pdf files.

You can unlock pdf files by using the **CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword** function which takes 2 arguments: a **CGPDFDocumentRef** reference to the pdf document and a **const char*** password. Opening the pdf file first with the **CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL** function will give you a **CGPDFDocumentRef** reference.

3. Now that you've opened the pdf file you'll need to draw each page individually to a UIView. This is the hardest part and takes a lot of work to get it done right. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints) on SO has helped me a lot while working on [my customizable framework](http://www.binpress.com/app/pdftouch-sdk-for-ios/859?ad=5107) for rendering PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [pretty good Kiosk-Example](http://pspdfkit.com/) that does the download, displaying the progress bar, saving the pdf in documents directory, displaying, opening - everything you want.

Password support is included, and looks like that:

```
const char *key = [passwordString UTF8String];
BOOL success = CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(pdf, key);
```