# Context Menus in PDFs

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, uimenucontroller

Built into UIWebView and QLPreviewController is the ability to highlight text and present some manner of context menu to the user.  While presenting the menu is the trivial part, determining the bounding rects of the lints of the PDF is beyond me.  Is there some API in Core Graphics that enables the analysis of PDFs for these ranges?

Comment: Are you trying to modify Safari's behavior, or are you displaying a PDF in your own app?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the question implies I want it in my own app, but in a style much like safari.

Comment: `UIWebView` uses the private `CorePDF` framework, which provides helpful classes like `UIPDFPageView` and `UIPDFSelectionController`.  Judging from the other defined and undefined symbols in the framework, it scans and and possibly renders the PDF itself using the CGPDF parsing methods/objects provided by Quartz 2D.  Anyone else who wants to know e.g. what text is under a touch is going to have to do the same.

Comment: Well gosh, CGPDF is a beast of a framework... It would be nice to have some exposed API's for this... I'll file me a feature request bug report.  In the meantime, is there any framework or class that duplicates these features?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out something like the omni framework to see if it handles what you need? Sounds like you want to alter the onselect event inside the pdf you are viewing. Check out this link: http://www.omnigroup.com/company/developer/

Comment: Omni's frameworks were download (and failure) number one.... Unfortunately, most of their relevant code is cocoa-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the answers to this question:

[PDF Viewer iPad App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949809/pdf-viewer-ipad-app)

There are at least two commercial libraries mentioned that look pretty serious and might have support for what you need.

There's also https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten - not mentioned in that page.

By the way, the iBooks two-touch selection only works in ebooks.  iBooks doesn't support selections at all in PDFs.

Comment: I know about the ebooks only selection, 'Tis why it would be such a cool find!  But anyways, PDF kitten is for searching PDF's.  And then again, the other libraries are overly unnecessary...