# How to add bookmark feature when using UIPageViewController to open PDF file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Created pdfscrollview and added it to the viewcontroller. Using uipageviewcontroller datasource methods to turn pages forward and backward

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Want to add bookmark feature to this loaded and opened pdf file like if user bookmarks any page then next time when user opens pdf file it should open right from that bookmarked page.

Anyone knows how to code for adding bookmark feature to pdf file.

Comment: What are you using to open PDF?

Comment: Basically created pdfscrollview and added it to the viewcontroller. Using uipageviewcontroller datasource methods - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController    
to turn pages forward and backward.

Comment: edit the question and put above code in it to protect the question, otherwise it is a matter of time before it is getting removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add fetures to your pdf viewer don't start from scratch, you will not get that help, there are some awesome helpful libraries on github which you can use:

[Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

[FastPdfKit](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit)

And if you are looking for really advance features you can check [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com/), by the way it is commercial.

Plus check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949809/pdf-viewer-ipad-app) question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.